# Using `split` function in VBA to find how often a text contains a certain symbol

Tags: string, vba, split

For a MWE, and to replicate my problem, in a blank workbook put the text

```
testone|testtwo
```

into the first cell, A1.

Then, the VBA code shall be:

```
Sub test()

MsgBox "testone|testtwo"
MsgBox Cells(1, 1).Text
MsgBox Split("testone|testtwo", "|")
MsgBox Split(Cells(1, 1).Text, "|")
Msgbox Split(Cells(1, 1).Text, "|").Length

End Sub
```

Now, already the second one gives me an error, type mismatch.

What I need this for is that I am faced a potentially long string in which `n+1` substrings, of different lengths, are separated by `n` occurences of the symbol `|`. I need to extract each substring, i.e. those `n-1` within two instances of the symbol, and the two at the beginning. I believe, but am not certain, that the use of the `split`-function is best. In a next step, want to use the `Length` of the result to count the number of occurences of `|` (as in the last line), but that does not work either.

Comment: Hi can you rephrase n+1 or n. From what I understand theres a string with '|'. Your goal is to count occurences of '|' and also to get the strings separated from '|' is that correct?

Comment: Yes, indeed. But I do not understand in what way you want me to rephrase `n` and `n+1`.

Comment: Sorry not very good with notation, so I was confused. If your aim is to get the number of occurences of "|" then the answer below by braZ will give the right answer. vSplit will will store an array of the split words. Ubound will return the highest index number of the array. "Test1|Test2" will split into Array(Test1,Test2) with index [0,1] highest index will be 1 which is also the occurence of "|". Ubound + 1 will return the number of strings, since highest index which is 1 +1 will equal 2, the index of arrays start at 0.

Answer (score 2):

Store the split in an array

```
Dim vSplit as Variant
vSplit=Split("testone|testtwo", "|")
```

then to get a count of how many items:

`nCount = UBound(vSplit) + 1`

If you want a count of how many "|" are in the string...

`nCount = UBound(vSplit)`